# Use single ResourceDictionary for multiple themes WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a control that has a lot of themes and each theme is represented by a ResourceDictionary. The problem is that the dictionaries are almost identical and they differ only in the beggining where I have declared color brushes, for example:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FirstRd1" Color="#3F555555" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondRd1" Color="#00000000" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThirdRd1" Color="#FF333333" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="FourthRd1" Color="#FF000000" />
```

These brushes (and other xaml objects for style) are used here and there on the same place, like this:

```
 <!-- ResourceDictionary 1 -->
 <Border CornerRadius="4"
         Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" 
         BorderThickness="1"
         BorderBrush="{StaticResource FirstRd1}">
         <!-- Some content -->
 </Border>

 <!-- ResourceDictionary 2 -->
 <Border CornerRadius="4"
         Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" 
         BorderThickness="1"
         BorderBrush="{StaticResource FirstRd2}">
         <!-- Some content -->
 </Border>
```

How to move the same elements with different brush like above in a single file? There are aslo other elements that do not depend on the brushes, but they are nested or have nested dependant controls. What will be the best solution in this situation, as I do not want to edit 15+ files for a single dummy change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge resource dictionaries.  Declare your common stuff in one file, then for the differentiated parts make each one it's own file and merge it with the common file.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx

Comment: I know about the merge option, but currently I can't use it as the controls are thightly coupled, for example the main border depends on the predefined brush and every other control is nested in this border. Inside these controls there are other controls that depend on the brushes, so I can't just move the independant parts.

Comment: Probably you must replace StaticResource with DynamicResource to decrease cohesion